# How to fix sampling pattern(always hit middle point of a pixel) in path tracing in Blender 3.0?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

i.e. disable anti-aliasing

I know it could be achived in Blender 2.93, using branched path tracing, by setting render sample to 1 so as AA sample fixed to 1, the problem is that the max number of branched samples can't exceed 1024, while I want result image as noise-free as possible.

It seems that you can choose between sampling patterns and at most guarantee the pattern between pixels are the same by setting seed to a fixed number, but you can't disable it.

Any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: You're talking about sub-pixel sampling here?

Comment: @AllenSimpson Yes, I want all the AA samples to hit the same point of(within) the pixel